# apt in Linux Subsystem for Windows 10 is failing with 404 Not Found

Tags: bash, gcc, windows-10, installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

OK, so this is my first SO question so I'm gonna try my best to lay this out.

I have a Windows 10 laptop on which I am trying to install `gcc`. I have in the past tried alternatives such as netbeans, cygwin and various emulators and virtual machines all to no avail.

What has been working so far is that I enabled the 'new' windows developer mode which allowed me to download a Linux bash shell from the windows store. It works for all the regular Linux commands, but doesn't have gcc installed.

When I type in `gcc` (or `gcc --version`) in the shell, it prints the following line:

> The program 'gcc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt install gcc

Which I tried, it then ran through a bunch of installer stuff but consistently seemed to run into errors such as the following:

> Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libdpkg- >perl all 1.18.4ubuntu1.2
>
> 404  Not Found [IP: **INSERT IP ADDRESS HERE** ]

where the ip address is different on each error line.

It ultimately fails with the following line:

> Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

I have tried but again I get the same kinds of errors as above.

I would really like to get `gcc` working in the Windows/Linux shell as it is working great for everything else, and I'm trying to keep the number of programs on my computer to a minimum.

Does anyone know why this isn't working, or how (if possible) I can make it work?

P.S I do need it to be `gcc` because of school reasons

Comment: @ikegami: You're right. I misread the post. Comment deleted.

Comment: Can you ping archive.ubuntu.com from the subsystem? How about google.com? Are you behind a proxy/firewall?

Comment: no firewalls that i can think of :( and it seems to do some of the initial connections fine

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post when I found my solution, turns out it must have been an issue with the schools internet as i was able to do the download when I got onto a different Internet connection.

Answer (score 34):

For what it's worth: I landed on this SO topic after having a similar issue.

What fixed it for me was to run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I guess the repo URLs were too old, even though my Ubuntu was in a recent version.

Comment: Just `sudo apt-get update` worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into the same thing attempting to install `python-pip`. According to [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/278152/how-to-update-the-windows-bash-shell/), this happens when you have the Windows 10 Anniversary Update (older) instead of the Creators update (newer). The solution is to either uninstall and re-install Ubuntu, or upgrade it (from 14.04 to 16.04). I found the upgrade to be simple and painless:

`sudo do-release-upgrade`

To check what you have, before and after via:

`lsb_release -a`

Comment: The reason you get a 404 when using 14.04 is because 14.04 is EOL and the repositories no longer exist but the OP is already using 16.04 (xenial).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Pinging the IP resulted in no response and visiting the website returned a 404.

I found a ppa with most current GCC and registered the PPA and was able to successfully install GCC with it; [ppa website](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test). I used GCC to build some software I wanted that was not found with `apt-get`.

From their page:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem that apt can't find its default repositories. It just works around it for `gcc` by adding a third-party repository.

Comment: @Vince The op says they "really want gcc working". They don't don't even mention that they care about broken repo. I get your point but I don't think it warrants a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Ubuntu application in Windows with an option "Run as Administrator".